# Looking for SpanIncluding equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, c++, string, mfc

I'm porting a c++ class to C# and i have a difficulty.

I would like to find an equivalent of SpanIncluding.

Here is my cpp code :

```
while (Notes.Mid(j,1).SpanIncluding("0123456789").IsEmpty()!=NULL){}
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Do we need to guess what SpanIncluding does ? It does not appear to me to be a standard function.

Comment: Briefly explain what you want to do instead of SpanIncluding.

Comment: I couldn't find `Mid` nor `SpanIncluding` in my C++ books.  What standard library is it from?

Answer (score 2):

I believe `SpanIncluding` starts matching from the start of the string, stopping when the first non-matching character is found.

So one formulation in the general case would be this:

```
string match = new string(someString.ToCharArray().
               TakeWhile(c => "0123456789".Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

(or an equivalent using a regular expression).

However, in the example given in the question there's **only one character** so the whole thing probably boils down to a test of whether this character is `>= '0'` and `<= '9'`:

```
while(char.IsDigit(Notes[j])) { ... };
```

Comment: +1 for managing to decipher what the darned snippet is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the MSDN page for [SpanIncluding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fhyz756%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and it seems like a ridiculously specific function. I can't really understand what it tries to solve, since it has some strange caveats.

LINQ would be one way of implementing it:

```
string text = "2334562";
IEnumerable<char> spannedChars = text.TakeWhile(c => "1234567890".Contains(c));
```

This is a more direct port of `SpanIncluding` than queen3's option, if I understand the MSDN page correctly, because the result set should stop the minute it hits a character not in the spanning string.

Comment: Hello Spanincluding is an MFC function.

Comment: Yes, I know, I linked to its MSDN page. That doesn't change the fact it's logic is extremely convoluted. Its description on MSDN seems less like a function description and more like a freshman programming exercise.